# How to get Android Studio to shut up about updates

Tags: android

I've used plenty of programs and none are more annoying than Android Studio about updates. It seems that I'm bothered to update almost every day. This plugin, that plugin, emulators, the studio itself.

Any way to get Android Studio to just leave me alone and let me build apps?!

Thanks!

Comment: It is good to be updated while working on android studio. If you want to disable those updates, do it by the answers provided below but I will recommend you update android studio (gradles, plugins etc.) when you have free time

Comment: Updating android studio will give you the better working knowledge upon what's new going on. Then you can adopt easily and can be able to sync with good dev-ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow below steps. But after unchecking this you need to do manual checks for updates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! So many options, I don't know that I ever would have been able to find this. +100 cool points for the pics.

Comment: @user249705 Pleasure to help you... Can I get an upvote as well for this?

Answer (score 2):

In Studio move to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Updates . Uncheck "Automatically check updates for".